# Azure AD - .Net Core 2 - How can I use two different Client IDs?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, .net-core-2.0

So, we have a web API that is working great with Azure AD and bearer token authentication.

In my ConfigureServices I have this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = Configuration["Azure:AD:ClientId"];
    options.Authority = $"{Configuration["Azure:AD:Instance"]}{Configuration["Azure:AD:TenantId"]}";
});
```

We have the Client ID setup to be a Web API app in Azure AD.

Now we are making a native application and we need to also have a native app client ID in Azure AD. My API is looking for the Web API client... how do I also allow a bearer token that was created with the native app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! So... we got this working.

For posterity here is what we ended up doing.

We found this fine link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation

In step 2 of this, it tells you to change the Web API URI - We ended up not needing to do this...

What was critical thought was to add the permission from the Native app to the Web API (the second set of steps in #2). Basically, as I understand this, it allows the native app and web api app to work together and share a client id when it come to an authentication perspective.

We also found that editing the manifest on the Native app and make "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" = true was also important.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is looking in the `aud` claim // `audience` field to verify the client ID. This field represents the app ID of who the token is intended for. This means if you register a new Native app registration, the tokens issued to that app for this API will have the same `aud` claim.

In v1.0 format tokens, they also have a `appid` claim which represents the App ID of the client application (your web app or native app for example) if your API is trying to verify the token was issued to one of your clients.

In v2.0 tokens, this claims is `azp`.

Do note,in the case of the native app, it's considered a public client meaning the exact identity of the client is not guaranteed, hence the name public client.  Your web app is a confidential client so there is a stronger guarantee the `appid` claim will be the app it claims to be.

In both formats there's another claim (`appidacr` and `azpacr`, respectively) that represents the client type. You can have high confidence if the value is `1`or `2`, but should be careful in the case it's `0`.

[Reference for tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens)